# Scrape Data i can't get

Tags: python, web-scraping

i have this issue, i need to scrape from this html data `"<h4 data-v-2acc9040="" itemprop="name" class=" tw-text-xl tw-font-bold tw-text-gray-600 tw-py-0 tw-my-0 group-hover:tw-text-link-hover"> Anglicare At Home Southern Region </h4>`

I need to get the name of the company: "Anglicare At Home Southern Region"

From this link: https://www.agedcareguide.com.au/search/in-home-care/aus?page=1

I need to get each name of each company from that page. (I know how to create the loop after i get the name, but i just can't get the name!)

I used this code but it prints `"None"`:

```
company_name = soup.find("h4", itemprop="name", class_=" tw-text-xl tw-font-bold tw-text-gray-600 tw-py-0 tw-my-0 group-hover:tw-text-link-hover")

print(company_name)
```

I don't know how to get this data. Can you help?
Thank you!

Comment: It is highly likely that the data on the web page is dynamically generated. BeautifulSoup only works well on static content. You can look at this https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-scrape-dynamic-web-pages-with-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-fa593235981 or this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-content-from-dynamic-websites/ for technique of using a web driver to load dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to scrape data using requests and not Selenium. I consider
that scraping data from the HTML code is a very tedious work.

Now, if you check your Dev Tools from the web browser, you can fetch the API request that the web page is using. In your example:

[image]

So, you can copy the cURL (to Postman or https://curlconverter.com/) and convert it to Python language:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.agedcareguide.com.au',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.agedcareguide.com.au/search/in-home-care/aus?page=1',
    'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}

params = (
    ('state', 'aus'),
    ('category', 'in-home-care'),
    ('page', '1'),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.agedcareguide.com.au/api/v3/search/1/compiled-profiles', headers=headers, params=params)
json_response = json.loads(response.text)
```

Finally, you can get what you want (and much more) treating the data as a JSON (or a dictionary):

```
data = json_response['data']
names = []

for item in data:
    names.append(item['attributes']['name'])
```